# How to detect memory leak in c# application?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a c# application which runs in kiosk mode (any interaction with the machine is limited to the application itself) 24x7 hours a week.
After about 20 days there is an **OutOfMemoryException**

```
FATAL System.OutOfMemoryException: 
in System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender()
in System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
in System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
in System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,  IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
in MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
in MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
in System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
in System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The exception trace gives no help, anyway I think it is due to a memory leak and not to what the application is computing at the moment of the exception. The application makes calls to unmanaged code in Windows dll, I suspect the problem is there, but I have no idea how to investigate. I cannot interact locally with the machine once the application is launched and don't know how to remotely check the memory consumption. Perhaps I can start logging data from the application itself or from Windows Performance monitor. What tools can help finding the bug ?

Comment: Can't you run the application locally, and reproduce the issues?

Comment: You can set up PerfView to capture data, based on various triggers. E.g. PerfView can monitor when a particular performance counter indicates that memory usage has passed a particular threshold, and take a snapshot (or multiple snapshots) and then shut down, ready for when you next visit the kiosk. You will need to experiment locally however

Comment: @canton7 Unfortunately I don't have a test environment with the same hardware and devices of the kiosk at my disposal for 20 or more days. People interact with the kiosk and I suspect in the process memory  is allocated and not released. I love c# because till today I have never had to worry about memory leaks and I lack tools and skill to find the source cause.

Comment: If you're doing unmanaged memory management, and also not worrying about memory leaks, that probably goes some way towards explaining the problem! I recommend getting familiar with PerfView